# What does tests $1,%al do in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, bitwise-and

So there is a value in %eax = x.

I have the lines:

```
tests $1,%al
je .L2
```

So I know it is doing 1&%al and then jumps if equal. My question is what is%al given %eax is x (I know %al is the least significant byte. I want to know what it is in term of x). And what does it mean for it to be equal to 1??

Comment: Why the `c` and `gcc` tags? Does this pertain to generated assembly from the compiler? Maybe it would help to see the associated C source line.

Comment: I am making c code from the assembly. I know that the test has to do with an if statement.

Comment: It will jump if `al` (and therefore also `ax` and `eax`) is even.

Comment: Danke!! And that is because al&1 for an odd number = 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of x, %al is really only the least significant byte. What you're doing is looking at just "part of x", or the part that contributes values of up to 255 to the total value of x. Might sound vague.

One thing this could mean is that x is odd because it has a least significant 1, in which case you don't have to look at x as a whole. I couldn't safely draw any other strong conclusions.

Comment: It does check if `x` is odd or even, and jumps for even (`je` is `jz` which jumps if the result is zero). Works for any `x`.

Comment: Oh looks like I came back with the wrong problem description in my head. I'll just get rid of the edit.

Answer (score 1):

EAX register (the accumulator register) can be logically divided into:

- AX 2 least significant bytes (16 bits),
- AH high byte of AX
- AL low byte of AX (least significant byte overall)

What it means depends on what is using your accumulator register.

It is typically used for IO access, arithmetic and interrupts.

If this is generated from some C code could it be assuming that the type of X is a byte and you don't need to send a larger word down the pipeline for the comparison?

Answer (score 0):

AL is the least significant byte of EAX.

Comment: So this would be like `(x & 0x0FF) == 1`?

Comment: No, it's `(x & 1) == 0`. Read the instruction set reference.

Comment: Well it's actually `((x % 256) & 1) == 0`.